# Angular $event undefined in Firefox

Tags: firefox, angularjs

As said in the [angular api docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angMouseenter), ng-mouseenter makes event object available as `$event`.

HTML:

```
<div ng-mouseenter="enter('test', $event)">Enter mouse over here</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.enter = function(data, $event) {
    console.log($event.x);
};
```

[Use this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/445/) and notice that...

- in chrome the log gives: `77` (or another number)
- And firefox gives the log: `undefined`.

Am I using `$event` the wrong way or does `$event` not work in Firefox?

Comment: You are logging the `.x` member of the event!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$event` is available in Firefox, but `$event.x` isn't. Try `$event.clientX` instead.

Notice that in Mozilla's [documentation for `MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) there is no `x` property.